# Confused on how to isolate for Y

Tags: abstract-algebra, recreational-mathematics

Had this equation come up in class, I know the answer is
$$y=\frac{x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 8}}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{x +\sqrt{x^{2} + 8}}{2}$$

but I am not sure how they got there from.
$$x = y - 2/y$$/

I'm just curious so if anybody could help explain it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation by $y$ and you get a quadratic equation.

Comment: If you follow @M.Wind's suggestion, and pull all the terms to one side, you can then use the quadratic formula. One of your coefficients will be $-x$, but don't let that hold you back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply the equation through by $y$ you get

$$xy = y^2 -2$$

Move everything to one side and you get

$$y^2 - xy -2 = 0$$

Treating $x$ as a constant, this is just a quadratic equation in $y$, so we can apply the quadratic formula to it. The "$b$" that goes in the quadratic formula depends on $x$ but that doesn't matter, we can just plug it in anyway.

Comment: Before you multiply both sides by $y$, you need to consider the possibility that $y=0$.  But that is readily ruled out in this case.